# How can my mid-2012 MacBook Pro Retina 15 run a 4K panel at 30Hz over HDMI?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have the first gen MacBook Pro Retina 15" (mid 2012) laptop. I'm on the latest MacOS X (10.9.4).

[image]

I just ordered the [Seiki SE50UY04](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BXF7I9M) which is a 50" 4K @ 30Hz display.

How can I run that display off my laptop, preferably right off the HDMI port on the laptop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I got the display and it works just fine - power it up and connect the HDMI cable and it's set to 4K @ 30Hz (the panel's limit).

Sometimes when coming out of sleep, the HDMI panel keeps cycling through a black screen, displays "snow" or digital white noise. Sometimes it goes for 5 or more minutes! It's a weird bug and I know that opening the macbook pro lid helps it get quickly out of this weird mode. I think this might be a Mac OS X bug.

On a side note, at the native 4K resolution, everything looks the right size on the screen at 3' away but the panel is a bit too big. I have to move my head quite a bit - like when talking to 2-3 people at a party and you have to move your head to make eye contact ... maybe should have ordered the 39" display...

***UPDATE***

So I also bought a VIZIO 50" 4K display ("P502ui-B1E") and a new Macbook Pro 15" Retina Mid 2014 (GeForce 750M)

The VIZIO has an HDMI 2.0 port so can do 4K @ 60Hz *but* I noticed that Mac OS X (10.10.2) can still only do 4K@30Hz over it's in-built HDMI port while the same machine, when booted into Windows 8.1 (Bootcamp) *can* do 4K@60Hz very easily.

Comment: Do you have an update on this? It bothers me that Windows Bootcamp can drive the monitor at 60Hz but Mac OS X can't!

Answer (score 4):

See the [official Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-lb/HT202856) for details, but the bottom line is:

- HDMI ports can do 30 Hz or below, on all MBPR models.
- Thunderbolt ports can do 60 Hz, but with only one monitor at a time, and only if you have a discrete GPU, and only on 2013 models and up.

Answer (score 2):

There is [no Mid-2013](http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2013.html) Macbook Pro. If you have an early 2013 model, you can't run the 4k display due to hardware limitations. If you have the late 2013 model, [you can indeed.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6008?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) By default, it runs at 30 Hz. If you enable Multi-Stream Transport on the external display, you can run it at 60 Hz via the Thunderbolt 2 port (equipped with DP 1.2 technology).

Comment: I have the mid-2012 model actually (updated screenshot). Also after I got your answer, I found some anecdotal evidence [here](http://9to5mac.com/2013/12/16/review-seikis-39-inch-4k-tv-as-a-display-for-a-2013-macbook-pro-with-intel-iris/comment-page-1/#comment-179300) and [here](http://www.amazon.com/review/R298RHCWY6L9II/ref=cm_cr_rev_detmd_pl?ie=UTF8&asin=B00DOPGO2G&cdForum=Fx3Q2HCHP1OKIVK&cdMsgID=Mx3V002SQH5WV35&cdMsgNo=1&cdPage=1&cdSort=oldest&cdThread=Tx25P7CF2KEM80L&store=electronics#Mx3V002SQH5WV35) that it might actually work. I'll post my own results too ...

Comment: [Another thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5471191?start=15&tstart=0) with more positive responses ... let's see! I get the display soon, worse case I have an extra 4K TV :) !

Comment: @DeepSpace101 you may manage to get it running via the HDMI port. Not sure about 30 Hz though, maybe 24? It definitely won't run via Thunderbolt port at all, though. BOL.

Comment: @njboot Got the ASUS PB287Q, got it to DP1.2, but I still get 30Hz only! Is the cable a possible factor for that? ( I got this one http://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-Mini-DisplayPort-Adapter-Cable/dp/B002XVYZ82/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1404835551&sr=8-2&keywords=displayport+cable )

Comment: @AntouanK What model machine do you have? Late 2013 Mac/MBP are only models equipped with DP 1.2 (aka Thunderbolt 2). Without these models, the limitation is on your Mac's end, not the monitor's.

Comment: @njboot Late 2013 MacBook Pro 13'', with OS X 10.9.4 (13E28). I contacted the company that makes the cable and they insist that it supports DP1.2 and 60Hz. They asked me whether MacBook supports HBR2... Also, when I have the ASUS screen on 1080p from the OSX display settings ( so you get 1080p with retina quality ), I get two selections for 30Hz! But ASUS still shows it gets 4k resolution @ 30Hz.

Comment: .@AntouanK Your MBP does indeed support 60 Hz @4K via the Thunderbolt 2 port (which contains DP 1.2 technology) . But, the caveat is it needs to be DP 1.2 > DP 1.2. IE, you can't use an adapter (say DP 1.2 > HDMI on the display). As long as the display has a DP 1.2 input, you have a Thunderbolt 2 cable, and **Multi-stream transport** enabled on the external display it should work. You need to enable MST. Ask the manufacturer of the 4k display how to do so. BOL.

Comment: @njboot I don't think it uses MST. "One of the first displays to support for 4K resolutions at 60Hz via DisplayPort’s Single-Stream Transport (SST) mode is the ASUS PB287Q.
http://www.legitreviews.com/asus-pb287q-28-4k-single-stream-60hz-monitor-review_142719 "

Comment: .@AntouanK Thanks for passing that along, though I can't make sense of how a monitor could use SST for 60 Hz 4K display *given the input*. [The whole point of implementing MST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) for 60 Hz is to enable one to use the maximum bandwidth available when connecting a single monitor rather than reserving such for Daisy-chaining or the likes. As I stated, contact the manufacturer of the display for assistance in this regard. If they claim such, and you paid that $$$, it should work as described. Best of luck.

Comment: .@njboot ASUS's repsonse is "Unfortunately the Asus PB287Q is not compatible with the Macbook and therefore you cannot run it on 60 hz." I obviously replied to them demanding a better explanation. My guess is that the MBP doesn't support SST ( which seems to be the way ASUS monitor works, rather than with MST )

Comment: Wondering how that guy got it working... https://twitter.com/joewalnes/status/482357258718703616

Comment: .@njboot I just tested a 15'' MacBook pro with the same screen and same cable. Works immediately @60Hz!! So what's different? The way I see it is that the GeForce the 15'' has, can enable SST, where the Intel Iris can't (?)

Comment: There is differences in GeForce and Iris. For example with 15' rMBP Early 2013 with GeForce I can run two Seiki 39' at 4k 30Hz (one connected HDMI second via mini display port to HDMI adapter). When trying to do the same on 15' rMBP mid 2014 with Iris the same adapter mini display port -> HDMI can output only 1920x1080.

Answer (score 2):

I purchased a Dell P2815Q 4K Monitor from the Microsoft site $299.00.  My mac is MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) 2.6 Ghz Core i7, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB will run at 3840 x 2160 I am running at 2560 x 1440

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am running 3840x2160@30Hz using HDMI cable with Macbook Pro 2012 (retina) on External Display SAMSUNG U28E590D 4K Display.

I hope running @60Hz using DisplayPort.

***The Text is too Sharp and Clear (@Retina)***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MacBook Pro Mid 2012 - Non-Retina 4K@60hz

[image: 4K@60Hz - Cable Thunderbolt 1.1]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't give image-only answers.  We're looking for answers that provide explanations as to why it answers the question as well as why it's the best answer.  Images alone can't provide detail or context.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -

Comment: @Fabio Sbano: So you're connecting the display via DisplayPort? Did you have to do any manual configuration?

Answer (score 0):

MacBook Pro 13 Late 2012 with S2712Q using mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort.

4K at 60Hz

[image: System information]