# Can MacBook Pro with Retina display (13", Late 2012) output above 1080p to 4k tv?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, hdmi

I have a late 2012, 13-inch MacBook Pro with Retina display. Apparently it has Intel HD Graphics 4000. I just bought a Seiki 50" 4k TV and would like to connect it to my laptop with as high a resolution as possible. I'm a programmer so I want the screen real-estate, don't care if the refresh rate is only 30 hz.

The Seiki TV comes with an HDMI cable, but when I plug that in, I only get 1080p (with 60hz).

This [1] person was able to get better resolution, but he has a 15 inch and a different graphics card.

I used this laptop with a different 27 inch monitor (one of the korean monitors on ebay) and was able to get 2560xforgot. If I remember correctly, I connected to the 27 using using DisplayPort, rather than HDMI.

If my laptop can't do more than 1080 output to the 4k monitor, I'm willing to upgrade my laptop. I'd like to stay at 13" rather than upgrade to a 15". Are there 13" MacBook Pro with Retina display which can output 4k to my tv? Do I have to get the latest or is there an older model which will do what I want?

[1] [How can my mid-2012 MacBook Pro Retina 15 run a 4K panel at 30Hz over HDMI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136856/can-my-mid-2012-macbook-pro-retina-15-run-a-4k-panel-at-30hz-over-hdmi)

Comment: Not over HDMI - you need to go DisplayPort or Dual-DVI to get the bandwidth.

Comment: Just adding a comment here with Apple's spec for 4K at 60fps support. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206587 Depending on the cable being used it varies a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

What's officially "supported" and what's possible don't match. I have a late-2012 rMBP and got 4K out of it at 30Hz.

I took a screenshot as proof: 
[image]
Just a normal mini-displayport<->displayport cable was used.

More details in my answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/147765/39878

or on this blog post: http://www.mattburns.co.uk/blog/2014/09/30/running-the-4k-aoc-u2868pqu-and-intel-hd4000-graphics/

Answer (score 1):

Only 2013 Macs (and upwards) are [compatible with 4K](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6008).

Current retina MacBook Pro ([13" and 15"](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-retina/)) are compatible with 4K but only at 24Hz

Answer (score 1):

Max supposed supported resolution on that card for an external monitor is 2560x1600, I'm afraid.
The 2013 can do 4k, but not the 2012.

Comment: Can my HDMI also do 2560x1600 or is that only for the display port?

Comment: The EveryMac description leaves me uncertain; possibly not - *This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single display up to 1920x1200 via HDMI. Although it can theoretically power all three external displays, as confirmed by a helpful reader, it runs too hot with three displays connected. http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.5-13-late-2012-retina-display-specs.html

Answer (score -1):

Here's your answer http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6008

This document from Apple explains